# How to change format of model's $dates property?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

in my laravel app I have a database column `travel_date` of type `date`. This columns was added to `$dates` property of the Eloquent-Model class. But if I assign the value `22.01.2015` to the model Carbon threw an exception

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing

in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '20.01.2016') in Model.php line 3015
at Model->asDateTime('20.01.2016') in Model.php line 2971
at Model->fromDateTime('20.01.2016') in Model.php line 2926
at Model->setAttribute('travel_date', '20.01.2016') in Model.php line 446
[...]
```

My code to create model is:

```
$trip = Trip::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['carpool_id' => $carpool->id])); //travel_date is 20.01.2016
```

And my `$dates`-Property

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at', 'travel_date'];
```

Thanks an regards!

Comment: Dates properties are expected to be in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format. So just save them in this format and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your trip this way:

```
$trip = new Trip();
$trip->property_1 = $request->property_1;
$trip->property_2 = $request->property_2;
$trip->carpool_id = $carpool->id;
$trip->travel_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '20.01.2016');
$trip->save();
```